# Run service on incoming SMS in android Oreo

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, receiver, android-jobscheduler

I'm developing an app which needs to run some code (Networking) whenever an SMS is received.
 In API 25 and lower it's fine, I register an implicit `receiver` in Manifest file and start my service in the specified class which extended `BroadcastReceiver`. In API 26 however you cannot register `android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED` in a `receiver` since it won't work.

From Android documentation:

> Note: If your app targets API level 26 or higher, you cannot use the manifest to declare a receiver for implicit broadcasts (broadcasts that do not target your app specifically), except for a few implicit broadcasts that are exempted from that restriction. In most cases, you can use scheduled jobs instead.

I've read several articles like [this one on medium](https://medium.com/@iiro.krankka/its-time-to-kiss-goodbye-to-your-implicit-broadcastreceivers-eefafd9f4f8a).  There are solutions like `JobScheduler` or `Explicit Receiver`, however the first one is used for changes in network state and I couldn't find a way to trigger the job on `SMS_RECEIVED` event and the second one is valid until your activity is up and running.

Because of the nature of my application I need to listen for incoming SMS whether the app is running or not. How to do that in API 26+?

**Edit**

Maybe the [code in JobInfoBuilder doc on android website](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobInfo.Builder.html) could help. It monitors the changes in the photos on a device and start the job on change. However I cannot find a proper Uri to do the same with the SMS (not even sure if it's possible to monitor SMS via `ContentObserver`)

Comment: I think job scheduler with periodic check method may be the correct solution.

Comment: @VVB I'm developing a TTS app that should play the sound when the SMS is received, however it seems that lowering the period time to detect the SMS received have a bad impact on performance and it's not a proper solution.

Comment: The `SMS_RECEIVED` action is exempt from the new implicit broadcast restrictions. https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcast-exceptions.html

Comment: @MikeM. Thanks. My terrible mistake here, I even searched for "SMS" in that exception list. However for those non-excepted receivers other than network related ones which could be triggered directly by `setRequiredNetworkType` [method](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobInfo.Builder.html) is there any way like `ContentObserver` (not sure about that) to do same job as implicit receivers?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. The `setRequiredNetworkType()` method sets which network must be present to run a given job. It doesn't trigger any job itself. As far as `ContentObserver`s, using `JobScheduler` would be preferable, if you're running on API level 21+. In either case, the URI for SMS is `content://sms`, and you can't get any more specific than that with the SMS Provider, for some reason. That is, you cannot observe only `content://sms/inbox`, the received messages.

Comment: Could you provide an example of how to do the same job as implicit receiver, with `JobScheduler` and `ContentObserver` for receiving SMS as an answer to my question? I can't find a proper example of doing that and I'm still not sure whether it could be done as a replacement for implicit receiver.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since there are lots of ways to do the job in android O, I post this answer and mention my approach to solve the problem. Obviously by problem I mean the general problem not the `SMS_RECEIVED` receiver itself.

I start a foreground service and in there I register a dynamic or explicit receiver to listen to the incoming calls (for instance):

In `MainActivity.java`:

```
String action = "START"
final Intent intent = new Intent(this, CallMonitorService.class);
intent.setAction(action);
startService(intent);
```

In `CallMonitorService.java`s `onCreate()` method where I have `BroadcastReceiver callExplicitReceiver` as a field:

```
    final IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
    intentFilter.setPriority(2147483647);
    intentFilter.addAction("android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE");
    this.callExplicitReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            if (intent.getAction().equals(TelephonyManager.ACTION_PHONE_STATE_CHANGED)) {
                // do the stuff here
            }
        }
    };
    registerReceiver(callExplicitReceiver, intentFilter);
```

and then in `onStartCommand()`:

```
    if (intent.getAction().equals("START")) {
        Intent callServiceNotificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        callServiceNotificationIntent.setFlags(
            Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent
            .getActivity(this, CALL_SERVICE_REQUEST_CODE,
                    callServiceNotificationIntent, CALL_SERVICE_FLAG);

        Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setContentTitle(CALL_NOTIFICATION_CONTENT_TITLE)
            .setTicker(CALL_NOTIFICATION_TICKER)
            .setContentText(CALL_NOTIFICATION_CONTENT_TEXT)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_info_outline_black_24dp)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setOngoing(true)
            .build();
        startForeground(CALL_NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
    }
```

and finally:

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    unregisterReceiver(callExplicitReceiver);
}
```

I think of this as a good approach since the user is notified of the running service because of the undismissable notification and that's what android `Oreo` wants, however through a button in the app user could stop the service and the monitoring receiver as a direct result of destroying service (I cleared that part of code).

Comment: I've done the same thing in my app - some people were confused about having the icon in the notification bar (it's there on 8.0 by default, not on 8.1) as it's a foreground service. Personally, I'd be getting annoyed if there's like 10 of these notifications. So not sure if Google thought it through. I have had complaints that some phone numbers don't trigger the BroadcastReceiver *at all* on 8.0. Have you seen that ?

Comment: I know the service is active at the time because I've added a bug report feature with a log and there's no messages that service is re-started.

Comment: @szmani20 is it still only solution right now?

Answer (score 3):

I think for now you are safe as `SMS_RECEIVED_ACTION` is present in the current exempted implicit broadcast [list](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcast-exceptions.html). Also, upon receiving the system broadcast you can either start a foreground service or schedule a job (to perform network operation in your case). Moreover, I am also using the same action and upon testing it seems to work okay.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I also needed to some other receivers which are not in that list. My approach was to start a foreground service and register  a dynamic (explicit) receiver in there programmatically and also to restart the service in boot startup. I'll post my approach as an answer.