# I am not able to receive “android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED” this broadcast in Android Oreo

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-broadcastreceiver, android-8.0-oreo

**This is my Menifest file**

```
<receiver
android:name="com.agribazaar.android.receivers.OTPReceiver"
android:exported="true">
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
</intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

**This is my Broadcast Receiver class**

```
public class OTPReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
   @Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {        
if(intent.getAction().equals("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED")){

}
}
```

Comment: Did you make your app  default sms app??

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46511807/run-service-on-incoming-sms-in-android-oreo

Comment: no it is not default sms app. i only need sms for otp.

Comment: But you should make it defult sms app. Otherwise it will not work. Is it working on Kitkat, Lollipop, Marshallow ??

Comment: Yes it is working fine in kitkat,lollipop,Marshmallow

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Run service on incoming SMS in android Oreo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46511807/run-service-on-incoming-sms-in-android-oreo)

Answer (score 7):

This fixed the issue for me -
I wasn't explicitly requesting permission at runtime for android.Manifest.permission.RECEIVE_SMS.
    In earlier versions of android it was working fine but in android O devices i got the issue.

```
int SMS_PERMISSION_REQ_CODE_SUBMIT = 101;
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.RECEIVE_SMS)
                            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){

        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(SmsActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.RECEIVE_SMS},
                                SMS_PERMISSION_REQ_CODE_SUBMIT);
}
```