# android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED can not be received in OREO. How can I solve this?

Tags: android

in AndroidManifest.xml,

```
<receiver ... >
  <intent-filter ...>
    <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
  </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

This can receive New SMS Message event until Android version 7.1.1
But this can not be functioned any more from Android version 8.0

How can I implement new SMS catching function on Android version 8.0 (OREO)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46511807/run-service-on-incoming-sms-in-android-oreo

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47674092/i-am-not-able-to-receive-android-provider-telephony-sms-received-this-broadcas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of this :
https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background

According to the above document, other implementation like JobScheduler(not only for foreground execution but also for background execution) is recommended for this problem :
example :
http://www.zoftino.com/android-job-scheduler-example