# How to use broadcast receiver to get alerted/notified when SMS arrives in Android oreo?

Tags: android, android-studio, broadcastreceiver, android-8.0-oreo

I know broadcast receiver wont work when app is killed in oreo, but i want to get sms data when app is killed. How do i do that? Is there any way to achieve this?
Oreo has been a sort of headache.

Comment: Why don't you use job scheduler?

Comment: check  this may be helpful for you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46511807/run-service-on-incoming-sms-in-android-oreo

Comment: @Ankush wont this service get killed as soon as user kills/removes the app from the task? specialy in Oreo?

Comment: You can use job sheduler for that. Sample code for this and the methods to achieve it are documented in the below blog post. http://midhunhk.github.io/dev/2018/08/05/content-observer-service/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Oreo, you can receive broadcast receiver for sms even if application isn't on memory as you mentioned it by 'killed'.

As you said, from android oreo, the broadcast receiver can't receive implicit intent even if it is defined on android manifest.

But sms receive is a whitelisted so you can receive it even if you application isn't on memory.

Please check below link.

https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcast-exceptions

Comment: Thanks for the info, i see its mentioned at the bottom about SMS_RECEIVED_ACTION in the documentation link you've mentioned. I am accepting your answer.